# URLs and Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

My bibliography contains plenty of URL resources of the format:

```
@misc{google-now,
  author = {Google},
  title = {Google Now},
  note = {\url{http://www.google.com/landing/now/}}
 }
```

By default, this gets translated into a one-liner, justified string, with parts separated by dots. How can I change this behaviour with a custom one, having, for example:

- Author and title on the same line
- URL on a second line
- Title emphasized
- Everything left-aligned

As an alternative, would it be possible to re-define a new "entity" just for URLS?

```
@url{author, title, page}
```

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use? Where should the information other than `author`, `title` and `note` be placed: on the first line or a new third line? Full justification vs left-alignment (aka flushleft and raggedright) would be set by document commands such as `\raggedright` and is independent of the remaining aspects of formatting the bibliography.